# How can i find the value of a variable through roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am making a Diagnostic Analyzer using Roslyn. I want to get the value of a variable in the code which is being analyzed. 
Such as getting the value of the variable `num` in this code:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] num = a;
Person person1 = new Person("bob", num);
```

I have tried compiling the code on the fly by creating a new Compilation Unit,

```
SyntaxTree compilationUnitTree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(
            @"using System;
             namespace HelloWorld
            {
                class Program
                {
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
                        int[] num = a;
                    }
                }
            }");
 var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation", syntaxTrees: new[] { compilationUnitTree });
 var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(compilationUnitTree);
```

But I was unable to get its value.
I have also tried using DataFlowAnalysis of SemanticModel, I am able to successfully check properties such as if the value is constant or not etc. but when I check for value of `num` it gives `a` and not what I expected({1,2,3}).

Is there any way I can get the value of a variable using Roslyn?

Comment: Well. The value of `num` is `a`, since it's only a pointer to `a`. You should analyze the value of the reference, once you find a reference.

Comment: How do I find the reference and its value through Roslyn Diagnostic Analyzer? and what if the case is that the value is given by reference recursively say :    int[] a={1,2,3}; int[] b=a; int[] num=a; and so on, also for the case if the value of b or a is read from an xml file @Herdo

Answer (score 2):

You can't in a generic way.

First it can be reduced to the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) you can't know if a program finishes so you can't know if `num` will ever receive a value, the code to fill it might throw for example or enter an infinite loop.

Secondly it might not be something that could be known before runtime : It might be initialized from a method that return a random value each time, call a webservice or give the weather of the day...

The problem can be solved in some cases (Like the one you describe) but while roslyn contains some [Static Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) algorithms (Like DataFlowAnalysis) I don't think that it contains this one.

If you do it yourself beware of reference aliasing:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = a;
b[2] = 8;
b = a;
int[] num = a;
```

What is `num` ?